# Return mean of observations for a given sample time

Tags: arduino-mega

new to this StackExchange site. I have an experimental setup with three inputs - two from a laser distance sensor to measure planar distance and one digital input from a set of callipers.

All sensors readings fluctuate over a small range (which is acceptable for my use case). Is it possible to have the Arduino record all inputs for a given period of time and output only the mean value for each sensor?

Comment: Just use an array. There's a tutorial on [Smoothing](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Smoothing) on the Arduino site that may help.

Comment: To make life easy: https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/Average

Comment: @Majenko That's pretty neat. Is there anything you don't have a library for?

Comment: @sempaiscuba I don't have one for making money :(

Comment: @Majenko That's a shame. I could really use one of them too. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611599/smoothing-data-from-a-sensor?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this:

```
int readElSens() {
  long sum = 0;
  int n = 0;
  long start_time = millis();
  while(millis() - start_time < 400) { 
    sum += analogRead(ELSENS_PIN);
    n++;
  }
  return sum / n;
}
```